# How to manually upgrade rooted Lenovo Vibe X2 to Lollipop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rom-flashing, rom

I have Lenovo Vibe X2-CU edition that was come rooted and has Android 4.4.2, how I can manually upgrade the device to latest official ROM and where I can get this ROM ?

I am new to this process so please give full details.

Comment: You'll be able to upgrade to latest stock ROM only if it exists, and if it does then your device should've informed you about it (you may check Settings -> About -> System Updates, or something). As for where to find it, see [this link](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device). Anyhow, know that  finding or suggesting off-site resources are off-topic here in case you don't know it.

Comment: the system update does not work, it exit with error message I think because the device is rooted